# Which one is correct for the usage of "s" suffix for multiple name exposition word case?

Tags: grammatical-number

Assumed A, B, and C are book name, which one of the following sentence is correct for the usage of "s" suffix in "book" word?

1. Are the A, B, and C books inside the box?
2. Are the A, B, and C book inside the box?
3. Both 1 & 2 are correct.
4. Everything is wrong (then say something about it ^^)

Comment: *books* because they are clearly a plural case, and there's no question of singular accord due to *C* being singular because "A, B, and C" is in itself plural. I know there is a duplicate question of this somewhere, but can't find it.

Comment: Here's a book entitled [***The Old and New Testament Connected:** In the History of the Jews and Neighbouring Nations](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=OEIVAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22old+and+new+testament%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=pjq1VKneK6ze7Ab_uoDwAg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22old%20and%20new%20testament%22&f=false)*. Given ***book*** and ***testament*** are just "nouns" in OP's and my examples it's not obvious to me singular can *never* be used like this. Unless it's *obsolete* (the book was published MDCCLXX, which I make 1770, despite Google Books dating it as 1725).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 1) is grammatical, though it is a bit unusual. Normally you'd just say

> Are A, B, and C in the box?

or if you didn't expect the hearer to recognise the names as book titles:

> Are the books A, B, and C in the box?

Your 2) is not grammatical.

(I have changed *inside* to *in* in my examples. *Inside* is grammatical, but I would only use it if I was making a contrast, eg *inside* as opposed to *next to* the box.)

Comment: I'm a bit confused, so both 1 & 2 are both correct but 1 is grammatical correct and 2 is grammatical wrong?

Comment: @suud- I don't think Colin ever said 2 was correct- It isn't. And it isn't because it's ungrammatical.

Comment: I don't answer questions about "correct", because to me that is a social question which depends on which guru of etiquette you choose to follow.